# Have point size monotonically increase in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

Consider the following list for example

```
ListPlot[{{0, 1}, {1, 4}, {3, 2}, {5, 6}, {9, 5}, {10, 8}}]
```

How can I obtain a graph, in an elegant simple manner, in which the size of the points monotonically increase with the index of the list?

- smallest point for first index (in this case {0,1})
- largest point for last index (in this case {10,8})

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 4}, {3, 2}, {5, 6}, {9, 5}, {10, 8}};
ListPlot[{#} & /@ data, 
 PlotStyle -> (PointSize /@ Subdivide[0.02, 0.06, 6]), Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
pts = {{0, 1}, {1, 4}, {3, 2}, {5, 6}, {9, 5}, {10, 8}}
BubbleChart[MapIndexed[Append[#, First@#2] &, pts]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also control the point sizes using the option `PlotMarkers`:

```
pts = {{0, 1}, {1, 4}, {3, 2}, {5, 6}, {9, 5}, {10, 8}};
{smin, smax} = {15, 40};
markers = Thread[{"●", Range[smin, smax, (smax - smin)/(Length[pts] - 1)]}];

ListPlot[List /@ pts, PlotMarkers -> markers, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 1, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]